# GAE: How do I read URL response line by line?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In Google App Engine, I tried reading a .txt file from a URL. Because the maximum allowed size is 1MB and the file is slightly larger, I'm using an alternative method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996170/google-app-engine-java-url-fetch-response-too-large-problems).

So, what I'm trying to do is this:

```
FetchOptions fo = FetchOptions.Builder.allowTruncate().doNotFollowRedirects();
HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(url,HTTPMethod.GET,FetchOptions.Builder.allowTruncate());
URLFetchService service = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
HTTPResponse response = service.fetch(request);
```

My question is now, how can I read this response line by line? I'm trying to process each line which should be possible somehow as the source file is a simple text file.

I can get a byte[] with

```
byte[] content = response.getContent();
```

but I'm struggling with the further processing of it.

Or, can I do something completely different to achieve the same thing ?

I'm trying to read it line by line because I don't need all the lines. Processing would be much easier than to put everything in one large string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bais, "utf-8"));

String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
 ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`IOUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) and call `IOUtils.lineIterator(reader)` (where reader is the `InputStreamReader`)

Comment: Very nice,thanks. I think it must be BufferedReader reader = new ... instead of Reader reader. The superclass doesn't have a method readLine(). If that's correct,can you please update your answer? Appart from that, it works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @socken23 yes, correct. I'm fixing it. Btw, by the rules of SO, you are invited to mark an answer as accepted, if it had worked for you.